# Error "className" is missing in props validation: but I'm extending React.HTMLAttributes?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong or it's just ESlint not doing the check correctly. I'm extending (in my `HeaderProps`) the `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` which actually have the `className` property defined:

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React from 'react';

type HeaderProps = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> & {
  children?: React.ReactNode,
}

export const Header = ({ children, className, ...props }: HeaderProps) => {
  return (
    <header className={classNames('flex-shrink-0', className)} {...props}>
      <>{children}</>
    </header>
  );
};
```

I could easly suppress or ignore the error but I'm too curious about that.

**EDIT**: actually, this should be the right definition, but the question still apply:

```
type FooterProps = Omit<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, 'className'> & {
  children?: React.ReactNode,
  className?: classNames.Argument,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `React.HTMLAttributes` abstract does not provide any `className` field.

`React.HTMLAttributes` is:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
  children?: ReactI18NextChild | Iterable<ReactI18NextChild>;
  }
}
```

`className` is a feature of `JSX`. It has nothing to do with `HTML`. So you should define `className` as a custom prop.

like this:

```
type HeaderProps = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> & {
   children?: React.ReactNode,
   className?: string
}
```